# Is the flow on a manifold with boundary diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, manifolds-with-boundary

$$\newcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}}$$
Let $M$ be a smooth compact, connected manifold with non-empty boundary.

Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$ and suppose that the flow $\phi_t$ associated with $X$, is defined on all $M$, for sufficiently small  $t>0$.

Is it true that $\phi_t:M \to M$ a smooth embedding?

I think that this is the case if $X$ is either tangent to $\partial M$ at every point of $\partial M$, or $X$ is strictly inward-pointing everywhere on $\partial M$;

I am not sure what happens when $X$ is tangent at some points of $\partial M$, and inward-pointing on other points.

Comment: Consider adding a collar to $M$ and extending $X$ from $M$ to the slightly larger manifold $N$. If $X \cdot n \le 0$ on $\partial M$ (which means that $X$ is either tangent or inward-pointing), this extension should be possible in a way that enforces $X \cdot n < 0$ on $\partial N$.

Comment: I'm not sure about this question,If vector field tangent to the boundary,$\phi$ is fact a diffeomorphism (and the foundamental thoerem of flow holds),If not tangent,given inward pointing vector field,the boundary flow out map is defined,which means $\Phi:\mathcal{P}_\delta \to M$ is smooth embedding,in particular if we consider the composition $p \mapsto (t,p)\mapsto \Phi(t,p)$ is also smooth embedding

Comment: The condition inward pointing is vital to keep the flow out theorem holds,so we can not use anymore,there is a hope using the double of manifold ,and extend the flow to the other side,since inward pointing of vector field or tangent to the boundary,the integral curve starting inside $M$ still lies in $M$.So I think it still holds.